# character encoding with asp.net dynamic textbox

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-controls

Environment: .net 3.5, c#, sharepoint 2010

Existing functionality: I have a user control with a search text box and search button. When the submit button is hit,  along with search results, a querystring with search keyword is built. On postback, the textbox is again populated with the search keyword from querystring. This works good.

Issue: Need to fix cross side scripting. so did a html.encode and again a filter to escape single quote with &amp#39; for the textbox value. but the textbox displays value as it is like "'searchingstring'".

I need to show the user only "Searchstring", but the value in the sourcecode should be &amp#39;searchingstring&amp#39; to prevent cross side script vulnerability.

(Note: Above text "&amp" is actually "&". not &amp#39. Since stackoverflow editor transforms it to single quotes, i replaced it with &amp for reading)

If i tried building the textbox dynamically on pageinit using stringbuilder, I am getting what i needed as i mentioned above.
eg:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (Request.QueryString["str"] != null)
        {

            string strName = Request.QueryString["str"].ToString();
            str_value = htmlCheckReturnData(strName ); //encoded string
            sb.Append("<INPUT type='TEXT' runat = 'server' id = 'mystring' value = '" + str_value + "' />");
            //    Response.Write(sb.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("<INPUT type='TEXT' runat = 'server' id = 'mystring' value = '' />");
        }

        ltlSearch.Text = sb.ToString();
```

But I need to check the value of the "mystring" text box inside pageload like,

```
   if (!IsPostBack && !Page.IsAsync)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mystring.Value))  //NOT WORKING HOW TO GET the textbox value
      {
       //do something
      }
   }
```

Note: If I create the textbox control on page_init  without a stringbuilder write method, the character with encoding displays on the textbox.

Any help?

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Appending a string in your html, with `runat="server"` does not make it a server control. You will have to add your control dynamically from code behind, in page_init like this:

Add a `PlaceHolder` control:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceHolder">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then this code in your `Page_Init` event to create the `TextBox` control:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = "myTxt";
    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

To get the Control from the Page_Load event:

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)myPlaceHolder.FindControl("myTxt");
```

now you can access the `Text` property like you would with any other control:

```
txt.Text
```

Couple of things. Adding controls dynamically could be sometimes a painfully experience. Asp.net is not handling this control's viewstate right now. So you might receive some errors depending on what you are trying to accomplish. There are tons of tutorials online that will help you in this process.

[Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET with Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515)

[TRULY UNDERSTANDING DYNAMIC CONTROLS (PART 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)

[Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, building dynamic control the way you suggested didnt fixed the Issue I mentioned.

Comment: @user2459457 You did not mention what method you used previously, you just said not with a stringbuilder.

Comment: My bad. sorry, I didnt mention that clearly. Thanks for your reply, it didnt fix the issue on character encoding display on textbox.